# Get user data Gmail API - JS

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I am trying to authenticate a user and get user data like name and email.
I am following the documentation from here [google](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js).
This is my code for authentication:

```
function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

function initClient() {

// Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = 
["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

// Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
// included, separated by spaces.
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

    gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function (data) {
    }, function(error) {
    });
}
```

When user clicks a button:

```
    if(!gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()){
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }

// user IS authenticated here
    var profile = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
```

When I `console.log(gapi.auth2)`, I see that I have function `BasicProfile()`, but if I use `gapi.auth2.BasicProfile().getEmail()` I am getting this error:

> cb=gapi.loaded_0:219 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of null
>       at Object.PG [as BasicProfile] (cb=gapi.loaded_0:219)

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
// The user is authenticated here
    gapi.client.gmail.users.getProfile({
        'userId': 'me'
    }).then(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
```